# block list across devices using different appleid

Tags: macos, ios, icloud

I understand if I block someone on one device, the person will also blocked on my other devices. I always believed this is done through iCloud, but something weird happened. I use different apple id on my iDevices and my computers, so they do sync contacts using different apple ids. What I found was block and unblock anyone on my phone get reflected on my macs and vise versa. I'm so puzzled. How does the block list get synced? I suppose it's still via iCloud, but how do they sync between two different apple id? Anyone knows how this work?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  I don't think they sync between Apple IDs, they must be using a different method.  What do you mean by "they do sync contacts using different apple ids"?

Comment: I mean both my iDevices and macs sync contacts to icloud but using different apple id. When block list sync between idevices, i assume it is done through contacts sync, but now there seems to be a different mechanism.

Comment: but what mechanism? how is it determined the two apple ids belong to the same person. more importantly, people uuse multiple ids because they want to keep things separate, why does apple think that forcefully merge info between two ids is a good idea?

Comment: Are you sharing or keeping those contacts in sync between those two Apple IDs?  For ex, 1 person can share their contacts with another person.  When changes are made, they're automatically synced to the other person.  My wife & I have this setup.

Comment: not really, but i figured out how the system works. the block list is shared via facetime and imessage using the same apple id. although i use different ids for contact sync, i do use the same id for facetime and imessage.